# asp.net can DropDownList display multiple column values from data source?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownlistfor

In my ASP.NET Web Forms application, I'm using a DropDownList1 which displays the one column value and lets me choose another column value to bind to the control from the linked data source. I'm using the configuration wizard to select the settings, but it only allows me to display one column value, but I really need to display 2 columns and their values(i.e. first and last name). Would I be able to display multiple column values using the DropDownList control or do I have use something else?

The is what I have in my .aspx page.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="LAST_NAME" DataValueField="ID">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:resourceConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [LAST_NAME], [FIRST_NAME] FROM [EMPLOYEE]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Which one you've tried: 2 cascading dropdownlist or using single dropdownlist to select both user's first & last name? I don't fully understand what you're asking, using an image to visualize your intent is recommended.

Comment: It is the "DropDownList" control from the standard toolbox in Visual Studio for my web forms application. That is the exact name and when I use that I can only display one column of data, but I want to display two columns of data. I don't know what cascading dropdownlist is and I have not seen it before.

Comment: Correction & clarification on my original question - my dropdownlist id is "DropDownList2" as shown in the code.

Comment: Let say I have 3 row of records with columns; Id, firstname and lastname with rows of records; 01 Jim Smith,02 Jane Smith,03 Tom Smith - so when I use the dropdownlist I want to display Jim Smith, Jane Smith, Tom Smith in the dropdownlist box and the user can select that record.

Comment: Oh, I see that you want to show multiple columns inside single DropDownList (multi-column dropdown) - you can try to use custom user control like [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11536/Creating-a-Multicolumn-Combo-Box-in-ASP-NET). If the control doesn't work, tell us what's going wrong with your implementation.

Comment: yes, now I remember doing something like that in MS Access forms and using the combo box controls. thanks for the link...will try to follow that, but I'm surprised that there isn't a simpler way of implementing the combo boxes since I see it being very useful in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking that there has to be an easier answer for what I wanted to accomplish, I was able to come up with a solution.

I made the data source something like `"SELECT [ID],  [FIRST_NAME], [LAST_NAME], [FIRST_NAME] + ' ' + [LAST_NAME] as NAME FROM [EMPLOYEE]"` and then I made the `DataTextField="NAME"` display the first and the last name.

Here is my working code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployeeId" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePalcam" DataTextField="NAME" DataValueField="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="200px" Font-Size="Large">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcePalcam" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:resourceConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ID],  [FIRST_NAME], [LAST_NAME], [FIRST_NAME] + ' ' + [LAST_NAME] as NAME FROM [EMPLOYEE] ORDER BY FIRST_NAME"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if the two fields you're trying to concatenate are the same data type, otherwise you'll get a conversion error.